# QGIS MSSQL on OSX?

Tags: qgis, sql-server, sql-server-spatial

I have an OSX machine, with QGis 2.12.1, and a windows instance with MSSQL running on AWS. For the life of me I cannot figure out how I will connect to that server. I can RDP into that machine from my OSX. 
QGIS tell me -

> [iODBC] [Driver Manager] Data Source name not found and no default
>   driver specified.

Could someone help me out with these parameters?

Along with the driver I have to fill out :

1. Connection Name
2. Provider/DSN
3. Host

Answer (score 2):

1. Connection Name is a name you choose for the connection to be listed in the Browser panel. Basically treat it like a file name in terms of allowable characters.
2. Provider/DSN can contain a connection string (for SQL Server, look at https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) for your particular database instance. It can be left blank at first, using info from the other fields, but try writing a valid connection string if blank does not initially work.
3. Host is the database server you are connecting to.
4. If you need to log in, fill in the username and password fields. Saving these is up to you.

Hopefully this is a good start. Fill in these 3 fields and then try the Test Connection button or List Databases button, which tests connection anyway.